# How do I create additional whitespace and then comment when knitting from R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to create additional whitespace between 2 consecutive code chunks and their outputs. Within this whitespace, I would also like to add several lines of comment, and I wish to place the comments on individual lines, separated by a one or two blank lines. This is my code:

````
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

This is my first comment.

This is my second comment.

````
```{r Nile}
summary(Nile}
```
````

When I knit this code to either a PDF or HTML document, the comments appear on one line. I would like for them to appear on 2 separate lines, with one or two blank lines between them. Moreover, I'd like to create some additional whitespace above and below these comments in order to separate the code chunks and their outputs from these comments. How does one do this in R Markdown?

Comment: Thanks Maurits! I also figured out how to add line breaks using <br>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either

- add two whitespaces after the first comment line to induce a single line break, i.e.

  ```
  This is my first comment.<sp><sp>
  ```

  where `<sp>` is a palceholder for a simple whitespace, or
- use `<br>` to induce line breaks

  ```
  This is my first comment.
  <br>
  <br>
  This is my second comment.
  ```

---

With bold comment text, either

- use two separate bold environments, i.e.

  ```
  **This is my first comment.**
  <br>
  <br>
  **This is my second comment.**
  ```

  or
- use HTML `<b></b>` tags

  ```
  <b>
  This is my first comment.
  <br>
  <br>
  This is my second comment.
  </b>
  ```

---

When knitting to PDF above solutions using HTML tags will not work. Instead you can do

```
**This is my first comment.**

\vspace*{10ex}

**This is my second comment.**
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Additional related question: How do I add line breaks when I bold comments? When adding 2 asterisks above and below a comment, and then adding <br> below this comment, R Markdown seems to ignore the line breaks.

Comment: Thanks again! Your recommendations appear to work when knitting to HTML, but not when knitting to PDF. When I use <br> to introduce line breaks and do not bold comments, these breaks appear when knitting to PDF. However, when I add asterisks to bold the comments, the line breaks no longer appear then knitting to PDF.

Comment: Yes HTML tags will only work when knitting to HTML. For PDFs you need to use the asterix syntax and resort to LaTeX code when you need additional vertical whitespace, see my second edit.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so very much for all of your edits, Maurits. This has been extremely helpful!